# Validation error:This package was built with an out-of-date version of the Windows SDK

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, visual-studio-2013, app-certification-kit

I am trying to upload windows 8.1 app package (the .appxupload file) created by visual studio, but getting error in dashboard while uploading this package. I am using Windows 8.1 Preview,  VS 2013 Preview for Windows Apps and Windows SDK for Windows 8.1 installed on the system. Application passes all validation tests while running on local Windows App Certification Kit. Following is the full error-

Validation error:   This package was built with an out-of-date version of the Windows SDK. Please update to the latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that Windows 8.1 is out, you need to use the released Visual Studio 2013, not the preview.